# Angular ui-router get asynchronous data with resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I want to display a form with data corresponding to the edited item. I use `ui-router` for routing. I defined a state:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.
    .state('layout.propertyedit', {
        url: "/properties/:propertyId",
        views : {
            "contentView@": {
                templateUrl : 'partials/content2.html', 
                controller: 'PropertyController'
            }
        }
    });
```

In `PropertyController`, I want to set `$scope.property` with data coming from the following call (Google Cloud Endpoints):

```
    gapi.client.realestate.get(propertyId).execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
```

I don't know if I can use `resolve` because the data are returned asynchronously. I tried

```
    resolve: {
        propertyData: function() {
            return gapi.client.realestate.get(propertyId).execute(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            });
        }
    }
```

First issue, the `propertyId` is undefined. How do you get the `propertyId` from the `url: "/properties/:propertyId"`?

Basically I want to set `$scope.property` in `PropertyController` to the `resp` object returned by the async call.

EDIT:

```
myapp.controller('PropertyController', function($scope, , $stateParams, $q) {

    $scope.property = {};

    $scope.create = function(property) {
    }

    $scope.update = function(property) {
    }

function loadData() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    gapi.client.realestate.get({'id': '11'}).execute(function(resp) {
        deferred.resolve(resp);
    });

    $scope.property = deferred.promise;
}

});
```

Comment: add a jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to read [the docs for resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve). Resolve functions are injectable, and you can use `$stateParams` to get the correct value from your routes, like so:

```
resolve: {
    propertyData: function($stateParams, $q) {
        // The gapi.client.realestate object should really be wrapped in an
        // injectable service for testability...

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        gapi.client.realestate.get($stateParams.propertyId).execute(function(r) {
            deferred.resolve(r);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Finally, the values for resolve functions are injectable in your controller once resolved:

```
myapp.controller('PropertyController', function($scope, propertyData) {

    $scope.property = propertyData;

});
```

Comment: The `deferred.resolve` is called but the controller is not called. It seems that the promise is stuck. If I replace my async call by `deferred.resolve("resolved")`, the controller is called. Any idea?

Comment: For some reason I had to call `$rootScope.$apply();` after `deferred.resolve`

Comment: It's because Angular's promise system is hooked into the scope system's digest cycle. For all of Angular's built-in APIs that leverage promises, it takes care of this for you. When you're using outside asynchronous APIs, you need to refresh the scope yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller function needs `$stateParams` parameter from which you can get your `propertyId`. Then you can use `$q` parameter and create promise to set `$scope.property` with something like this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

gapi.client.realestate.get(propertyId).execute(function(resp) {
    deferred.resolve(resp);
});

$scope.property=deferred.promise;
```

Here is [description of using promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) for handling async calls.

Comment: The `PropertyController` already exists, so by using the controller function `controller: function PropertyController($scope, $stateParams)`, does it create a new `PropertyController`, or use the existing one?

Comment: If it exists how does it look?

Comment: So go ahead and add $stateParams, $q to this definition: ...'ProperyController', function($scope, $stateParams, $q) { ...

Comment: I edited my controller. But I don't understand how to trigger the `loadData` function.

Comment: Why you need this loadData, and why you define it indside controller?

Comment: You can put the body of your loadData right into controller function. If you want more "separation of concerns" you should probably consider using [services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)

Answer (score 1):

Try this easy way to use  resolve in proper way

State code:

---

```
.state('yourstate', {
                url: '/demo/action/:id',
                templateUrl: './view/demo.html',
                resolve:{
                    actionData: function(actionData, $q, $stateParams, $http){
                       return actionData.actionDataJson($stateParams.id);
                    }
                },
                controller: "DemoController",
                controllerAs : "DemoCtrl"
            })
```

---

In the above code I am sending parameter data which I am sending in the url,For examples if i send like this `/demo/action/5` 
this number 5 will go to `actionData` service that service retrieve some json data based on id.Finally that data will store into `actionData` You can use that in your controller directly by using that name

Following code return some JSON data based on id which iam passing at state level

---

```
(function retriveDemoJsonData(){

    angular.module('yourModuleName').factory('actionData', function ($q, $http) {

        var data={};
        data.actionDataJson = function(id){
           //The original business logic will apply based on URL Param ID 
            var defObj = $q.defer();
            $http.get('demodata.json')
                .then(function(res){
                     defObj.resolve(res.data[0]);
                });
            return defObj.promise;  
        }
        return data;
    });

})();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function PropertyController($scope, $stateParams) {
   gapi.client.realestate.get($stateParams.propertyId).execute(function(resp) {
     $scope.property = resp;
   });
}
```

Comment: The `PropertyController` already exists, so by using the controller function `controller: function PropertyController($scope, $stateParams)`, does it create a new `PropertyController`, or use the existing one?